# Can .gch files generated from CMake's target_precompile_headers be shared across targets?

Tags: c++, cmake, precompiled-headers

My initial attempt at incorporating precompiled header files in my project resulted in very large (~200MB) and nearly identical .gch files for each target directory.  I tried the following approach, which I was hoping would produce a single .gch file generated and shared among targets.  However, CMake still generated separate .gch files for each target.

```
add_library(pch INTERFACE)
target_precompile_headers(pch INTERFACE project.hpp)

add_executable(target1 src1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(target1 PRIVATE pch)

add_executable(target2 src2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(target2 PRIVATE pch)
```

Is it possible to share a CMake generated .gch file across multiple targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `target_precompile_headers` per each target you want PCHs for. With one producer you use like you did and then the consumers should look like this:

```
target_precompile_headers(target1 REUSE_FROM pch)
```

And you do not need to link against your `pch` "library".

Docs actually have the [section](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_precompile_headers.html#reusing-precompile-headers) for it.